# Sending data from native android to webview javascript page reloads the webpage

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am showing a new registration form(javascript page) consisting of 3 pages on android webview and then on 4th page on button click inside javascript page, I compute something and pass some data from android to webview.

The problem is when I send data to webview page from android, it changes the state of the webview and all the previous form data gets erased.

I am passing data from android to javascript page like below:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:getData(" + data + ")",null);
```

I think this line reloads the webpage again but I am not sure.

Can anyone tell how can I achieve this without changing the state of webview? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `javascript:` scheme inside `evaluateJavascript()`, just pass the actual JS you want to execute.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("getData(" + data + ")", null /* callback */);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:getData('" + data  + "')");
```

1. same getdata method should be present on web side